# How do I get all the values of an array from an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, promise, callback

I would like to download an XML file, convert it to JSON, Fill an array, send Values to an different API.

The things that work:

- Download mulitple XML files
- Convert it to JSON
- Fill an array with all the values

I can't get my head around the callback function. The code below will output:

Loading..
34
done
34
done

Expected is Loading..34 done

```
function fillArray(callback) {
    console.log("Loading..");

    for (let i = 0;i < urlArray.length; i++){
        
        xml2json(urlArray[i], (json) => {
            
            let myArray = findProp(json, "value");
            
            for(let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
                myArrlabel.push(myArray[i]);
               
            }
           
          callback();
        });
        
    }
    
    //return myArrlabel;
}

function useArray(){
    
    console.log(myArrlabel[15]);
    
    console.log("done");
    
}

fillArray(useArray);
```

The callback is inside the for loop, that's why I will get the above output. It could be a stupid question but I can't understand how to code this correctly.

edit.. added xml2json()

```
function xml2json(url, callback){
    http.get(url, (resp) => {
      let data = '';

      // A chunk of data has been recieved.
      resp.on("data", (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
      });

      // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
      resp.on("end", () => {

          let json = parser.toJson(data, options);
          callback(json);
      });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
      console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });
}
```

Comment: You call `callback()` (useArray) inside your outer `for` loop, I'm guessing that `urlArray` has a `length` of 2.

Comment: You need to call it on last iteration of for loop

Comment: This code needs to be rewritten a different way to work reliably.  I can show you a much better way to code this, but I need to see the doc or code for `xml2json()`.  Can you provide that?

Comment: Added the xml2json function.

Answer (score 0):

try adding a var that adds 1 every time data loads like your callback